# Understanding sorting solution to finding a triplet from each of 3 linked-lists whose sum is equal to a given number

Tags: algorithm

Question:

> Given three linked lists, say `a`, `b` and `c`, find one node from each list such that the sum of the values of the nodes is equal to a given number.
>
> For example, if the three linked lists are `12->6->29`, `23->5->8` and `90->20->59`, and the given number is `101`, the output should be the triplet `"6 5 90"`.

An `O(n²)` solution is described on [GeeksforGeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-a-triplet-from-three-linked-lists-with-sum-equal-to-a-given-number/): (paraphrased)

> `b` and `c` are sorted in ascending and descending order respectively using merge sort. Then, for every pair of `b` and `c` (1st element of `b` and 1st element of `c` form a pair and so on), we check for all values of `a`.

I'm not wondering about the implementation, just the algorithm. How does this algorithm provide right solution?

Comment: I fail to see why this requires sorting these elements in a tricky order. If you are OK with `O(n^2)`, it makes more sense to just use a hashtable to determine if `s-a-b` is in the `c` list, for every possible `a` and `b`. All this requires is sticking every element in `c` in a hashtable, no sorting needed.

Comment: Do you understand [the sorting solution to 3SUM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM)? That would be the obvious place to start, given that GeeksforGeeks mentions the similarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm basically converts the 3-SUM problem to a 2-sum problem.

You have list b sorted in ascending order and c sorted in descending order.

1. For each ai element in a, you have to check whether there is a pair (bj, ck) in b & c such that:

   bj + ck = SUM - ai

This can be done by traversing the lists b & c simultaneously.

Keep one pointer each for lists b & c (say p & q).

```
If (*p + *q == SUM - ai)
   return with success.
If (*p + *q < SUM - ai)
   p = p->next
If (*p + *q > SUM - ai)
   q = q->next
```

The idea is that p points to the lowest element in the list b and q points to highest element in c. So if the sum is too small, then a higher number in b needs to be considered and if it is too large, then a smaller number in c needs to be considered.